# YES/NO attribute on layered navigation

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation

How do you manage to show **Yes/No** attribute on layered navigation.

I did not find any extension for that !

It seems impossible to not be able to achieve this.

Comment: Did you get it ?

Comment: No I did not ...

Comment: You Mean to say like toggle checkbox dear @Sebastien in frontend layer navigation side.

Comment: Yes! That's what I was expecting natively

Answer (score 0):

You could add it as a dropdown, and then add just two options, Yes and No.

That would be a very easy work around.

Comment: It's not elegant....a checkbox will